# StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: ERR unknown command 'EVAL'

Tags: session, caching, model-view-controller, redis, provider

I'm running redis server locally and I get this error when running MVC app. 
Here is my configuration section:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="RedisSessionProvider"
      type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
      host = "127.0.0.1"
      port = "6379"
      ssl = "false"
      throwOnError = "true"
      retryTimeoutInMilliseconds = "2000"
      applicationName = "MyApp"
      connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = "2000"
      operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1800000" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider v1.6.5.0

StackExchange.Redis.StrongName v1.0.316.0

I already spent few hours trying to find solution online with no success.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest Azure SDK solved problems.